# I need a tool that hogs off stock to fix the side of a panel

Tags: tools, powertools, hand-tools

I need to fix a panel and this is exactly what I need but i don't know what its called. Can someone help me out?

https://youtu.be/teQYBrA7sX0?t=3m50s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tool being used in the video is a Power Planer:

[image]

The are normally used on wood to do the same job as hand plane, but they can be used on *soft* metal like aluminum.

I also found [this website](http://www.submarineboat.com/cutting_aluminum.htm) which talks about using the tool to clean up the edge of an aluminum panel.  I've never seen this tool used on metal before your question, so I can't tell you much about it.  It seems to me it would ruin the planar knives pretty quickly.

Also, planers like this are only designed to remove at most a 1/16th of an inch of material, and I'm not sure what the max would be on aluminum.

Comment: Depending on exactly what you're doing, sandpaper and a good sanding block, or a belt sander, might do a better job.

Comment: Time for some **serious** ear protection.